Strong Monotonicity vs Strict Monotonicity
I'm currently taking an undergraduate course by the name of Microeconomic Analysis, a slightly more rigorous version of intermediate microeconomics, and we were given the following definitions for strong and strict monotonicity:
Strictly Monotone: A function where f(x) is strictly preferred to f(y) whenever all quantities of goods in bundle x and bundle y are equal except for one good in x which has a higher quantity than the corresponding good in y.
Strongly Monotone: A function where f(x) is strictly preferred to f(y) whenever x >> y, or every good in bundle x is purchased at a higher quantity than the corresponding good in bundle y.
I understand, on paper, what the difference between these two definitions is. I get confused when I try and think about how these definitions are different in practice. Can someone give me a function which is strictly monotonic but not strongly monotonic? I was told strong monotonicity implies strict monotonicity but not vice-versa.

If strong monotonicity requires all elements of the one vector to be higher than those of the other in order to get strict preference, I don't see how by reducing the values of all elements (except one) to equality can guarantee that strict preference will continue to hold (i.e. that "strong monotonicity" implies "strict monotonicity"). Can you include in your post the exact mathematical definitions you were given?
